# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) on 'service mysql start'

Tags: mysql

Environment

```
$ uname -a
Linux aurora 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

MySQL

```
$ mysqladmin --version
mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux on x86_64
```

Clearly something is trying to log into my mysql server as **`root`** upon

```
service mysql start
```

but I don't know what it is.

The last line in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` related to starting the server is:

```
[Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

How do I figure the offending config file or server or application that is trying to log in as `'root'@'localhost'` on startup? What other information can I provide to help to understand and resolve this issue?

Also, I am able to log in as `'root'@'localhost'` if I do so explicitly. It's only the `[Note]` in the error log that is irritating me and that I want to debug.

In order to reduce the number of variables, I've also shutdown `apache` and deleted my `crontab` just in case that was part of the problem.

I am open to all suggestions.

Redirected from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601069/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no-on-service-mysql

Comment: Whether, the service started or not. Note is not an error. Also, if  started, check the error log now. In case of Access Denied error, check this page for more analysis http://www.rathishkumar.in/2017/04/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-user-host-using-password-YES.html

Comment: Could you explain my.cnf file?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098505/mysql-works-with-sudo-but-without-not-ubuntu-16-04-mysql-5-7-12-0ubuntu1-1

And solved id following by:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/766334/cant-login-as-mysql-user-root-from-normal-user-account-in-ubuntu-16-04

```
sudo mysql -u root
DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: I _think_ that my problem is not with logging in as root, but rather identifying what startup script/config file is trying to login as root without a password. I didn't think this would help but tried it anyway and have replaced my `'root'@'localhost'` with `'root'@'%'` but have not seen any change to the startup logs otherwise. Thank you.

Comment: So your root password to database is empty or not?

Comment: No. My root password is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

You set DB_PASSWORD=secret so pass null to it

```
DB_DATABASE=abcdef
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Change to :

```
DB_DATABASE=abcdef
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Hope it work